# Javascript: Autosubmitting form post data and not redirecting or refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to be able to auto-submit form post data and not have the page redirect like in my current code. Everything I come across on the subject involves jquery and ajax. I just can't get a working version using any of their examples.

Here is my current working page that redirects:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Does it work?</title>
</head>`

<body>
<form name="actionBalance" method="post" action="action.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value2">
        <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
        <input type="hidden" name="name3" value="value3">
</form>
</body>


<script>document.actionBalance.submit()</script>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no way to do this without the page reloading/submitting without AJAX.

Comment: Yes, the only way to not reload the page is using a JavaScript Ajax request. Have you tried [jQuery.Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)?

Comment: AJAX was created exactly for this purpose. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call jquery post method with your form data like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.post( "action.php", $('form[name=actionBalance]').serialize() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post("action.php", {name: "value", name2: "value2", name3: "value3"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it should be working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Does it work?</title> 
</head>
<body onload="document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('actionBalance'))"> 
    <form id="actionBalance" name="actionBalance" method="POST" action="action.php">  
        <input type="hidden" name="name1" id="name1" value="value1" />  
        <input type="hidden" name="name2" id="name2" value="value2" />  
        <input type="hidden" name="name3" id="name3" value="value3" />

        <input type=hidden name="submit" id="submit" value="Continue"/> 
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is put an iframe, so when page loads, then iframe load your payload (your form with the javascript that you put in your question) and the form will be submit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this solution with redirect right after submit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Does it work?</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('form').submit(); 
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="actionBalance" method="post" action="action.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value2">
        <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
        <input type="hidden" name="name3" value="value3">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Try to replace your whole script with this and let me know if this is what you wanted :-)

EDIT: If you need only that piece of script then jquery could be an overkill because it is huge library. So here is pure javascript for you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Does it work?</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="actionBalance" method="post" action="action.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value2">
        <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="value2">
        <input type="hidden" name="name3" value="value3">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var form = document.getElementsByName('actionBalance')[0];
        form.submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```